# Index was out of range using 2 picturebox lists

Tags: arrays, list, indexing, range, picturebox

I'm making a little game involving 2 picturebox lists and collision detection.
What I have is:

```
List<PictureBox> spells = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> enemy = new List<PictureBox>();
```

I then use functions to dynamically create new pictureboxes for each of these lists with their appropriate images.

Then the collision detection using a timer:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {for (int i = 0; i <= spells.Count-1 ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= enemy.Count-1 ; j++)
            {
                if (spells[i].Top == enemy[j].Top &&
                    spells[i].Right > enemy[j].Left &&
                    spells[i].Tag.ToString()=="Fire" && enemy[j].Tag.ToString()=="Frostenemy")
                {

                    Controls.Remove(enemy[j]);
                    enemy[j].Dispose();
                    enemy.Remove(enemy[j]);
                    Controls.Remove(spells[i]);
                    spells[i].Dispose();
                    spells.Remove(spells[i]);

                }
```

And repeat for the other types of picutreboxes. This works OK if there are less than 3 pictureboxes from the "enemy" list, which are generated by another timer, but as soon as there are more than 3 on the screen and I try to create a picturebox from the "spells" list, I get the following error:

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

I have looked up other solutions to this problem but I haven't really had any luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, try making your timer longer (slower, fewer ticks per minute) to see if the problem improves, but doesn't go away.

The timer may be firing off **simultaneous** runs of your function there -- which could cause all sorts of logical problems.